# Unable to connect via SSH to "Bash for Windows" (WSL)

Tags: ssh, bash, windows-10

I'm trying to SSH from my linux box to WSL and no luck so far.
I've studied:

- https://superuser.com/questions/1123552/how-to-ssh-into-wsl
- https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/300
- https://superuser.com/questions/1111591/how-can-i-ssh-into-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-10

I tried pretty much everything. Turning off firewall, different port, AllowUsers, PermitRootLogin, UsePrivilegeSeparation etc.
I actually can ssh from the Windows box to my linux box with no problem. And since I turned off the firewall on the windows system, I also get a "connection established" when debugging the connection (from Linux to WSL):

```
$ ssh -vvv 192.168.2.8 -p 2222
OpenSSH_7.5p1, OpenSSL 1.1.0e  16 Feb 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/user/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "192.168.2.8" port 2222
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.2.8 [192.168.2.8] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
^C
```

but no login appears, so I Ctrl+C it. The Linux box is an Arch Linux, SSH version see above.

I am pretty sure the problem must be on the Windows-box, as I get exactly the same result when - on the windows box - trying to locally ssh (ssh -vvv user@127.0.0.1 -p 2222): connection established, then dead.

Hopefully someone has more ideas how to.

Comment: What do the logs from the WSL box show?